# How to efficiently extract rows from large 2d array containing the lowest N values at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multidimensional array of x columns and y rows:

```
[
[11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
[4.8,   6.3,  3.6],
[6.6,   8.4,  5.2],
[37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
[12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
[16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
[12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
[30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
[5.3,   7.9,  4.7],
[25.4,   57, 25.7],
[11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
[8.8,  13.6,  7.7],
[4.2,   6.2,  3.4],
[7.6,  12.3,  9.6]
]
```

My goal is to return the rows that contain the N lowest values in index position 0, sorted from smallest to largest. I need the rows kept intact.

I naively achieved this using .sort and .slice in jQuery:

```
.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) // sorts the 2d array by column value
.slice(0, n);  // retrieves the lowest n values
```

Using 3 for n yields the following result:

```
[
[4.2,  6.2,  3.4],
[4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
[5.3,  7.9,  4.7]
]
```

But this is REALLY inefficient since sorting the entire list first is expensive for longer lists. I need to get the min values first, then sort the result. I'm struggling on how to do that.

What I really need is to build a new array with only the min values at index 0:

```
[
[4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
[5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
[4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
]
```

...and then sort that array by the 0th index:

```
[
[4.2,  6.2,  3.4],
[4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
[5.3,  7.9,  4.7]
]
```

Comment: *I'm trying to do this calculation hundreds of times a second* - how does the data get changed?  Obviously there's no need to sort n-times if the data hasn't changed.   One solution is to provide an index into your matrix, but the index would also need to be changed if the data changes (which should be less time consuming that sorting every time) - then you sort on the index values which gives you your row values.   Essentially a very light in-memory db/sql implementation of a table + index.

Comment: The data changes based on parameters set by input sliders. It runs in a browser. As the user drags the slider, the values rapidly change, requiring a complete recalculation of a 2d array and a resort / min value calculation at every value along the slider. I'm trying to make the slider feel snappy and smooth. It's a bit choppy with some parameters.

Comment: Not directly related, but consider `debounce` on your slider input- it will give the appearance of being smoother as it will then only update when the user stops moving (or slows moving depending on debounce timeout) rather than on every step.

Comment: I actually like the fact that it reacts instantly to slider inputs, aesthetically. There are other opportunities in the code to make things faster, just wanted to be sure this sorting step was as efficient as possible before evaluating the rest of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom algorithm for this solution.

**Full working example:**

```js
function findNLowestValues(arr, n) {
  var result = arr.slice(); // Create a shallow copy of the original array
  var nLowest = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let minIndex = i;

    for (let j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
      if (result[j][0] < result[minIndex][0]) {
        minIndex = j;
      }
    }

    // Swap the rows to move the minimum value to the beginning
    [result[i], result[minIndex]] = [result[minIndex], result[i]];
    nLowest.push(result[i]);
  }

  return nLowest;
}

var yourArray = [
    [11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [4.8,   6.3,  3.6],
    [6.6,   8.4,  5.2],
    [37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [5.3,   7.9,  4.7],
    [25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [8.8,  13.6,  7.7],
    [4.2,   6.2,  3.4],
    [7.6,  12.3,  9.6]
];

var n = yourArray.length; // Number of lowest values you want to find
var nLowestValues = findNLowestValues(yourArray, n);

// Sort the n lowest values by the 0th index
nLowestValues.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

console.log(nLowestValues);
```

Comment: Since the script is at the top of the snippet, there is no need to repeat the script. Just show the snippet

Comment: Thanks! I was able to achieve my earlier result with only 2 lines of code. Is there a more compact method to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: This code is also very low on longer lists. I was hoping the value comparison could calculate in O(n) time.

Comment: "*only 2 lines of code"* - well.... that's only 2 lines of your code, there's multiple lines in the library methods.  The same argument means that *this* answer is only one line of code: `findNLowestValues(..)`  (maybe 2 with an additional sort) - don't be afraid to create functions that are 1000s of lines long if they do what you want - as long as they're encapsulated, the actual length is irrelevant.

Comment: I like the convenience of library methods. I was only wondering if it was possible with those methods only. I'm guessing not.

Comment: This code actually doesn't need the last step -- it defaults to a sorted array automatically. Also, the array length shouldn't be passed into n. Otherwise a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> sorting the entire list first is expensive for longer lists

not true. JS can sort thousands of rows in a fraction of second.

```js
a = [
    [11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [4.8,   6.3,  3.6],
    [6.6,   8.4,  5.2],
    [37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [5.3,   7.9,  4.7],
    [25.4,   57, 25.7],
]

b = []
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
    b.push(...a)

console.log(b.length) // ten million

console.time('sort')
b.sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0])
console.timeEnd('sort')  // about 1 second for me
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this calculation hundreds of times a second. I need it to be fast. I don't want to sort 17000 items on a list hundreds of times a second, when the smarter solution is to first parse out the lowest value rows, then sort the result.

Comment: It's your call. Don't forget to profile whatever "smart" solution you come up with against the dumb sorter.